# Page display from another site

Tags: php

I am trying to display this site on my domain, and all external links don't have full domain name on where they pointing, is there a way around it? I don't want to use iframe.

Thank you

Comment: bookingprice.clientivity.com/m/home.php

Comment: This will get you site data in string format.

Comment: Best way would be via FTP

Comment: how can this be done

Comment: are you looking to host the entire site on your server?